# Counting the total number of a specific character occurrence in a column that contains multiple types

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am using Google Sheets to code some exercises from a textbook and part of the input is either M, F, or I. I want to count the number of F's, M's, and I's but I don't know how to code to find the number of occurrences of a character from a column.

I know this line of code finds the number of times the character comes up in a CELL.

```
=len(H11)-len(SUBSTITUTE(H11,"F",""))
```

I tried replacing the cell location to a range like "H11:H400" but it gave me an error.

Please help steer me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a column in place of the reference if you put it in a sum:

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(len(A2:A))-sum(len(substitute(A2:A,"F",""))))
```

Note that substitute is case sensitive so it can pick out M, F or I but would need changing to pick out m, f or i as well:

```
=ArrayFormula(2*sum(len(A2:A))-sum(len(substitute(A2:A,"F","")))-sum(len(substitute(A2:A,"f",""))))
```

or

```
=ArrayFormula(2*sum(len(A2:A))-sum(len(substitute(A2:A,{"F","f"},{"",""}))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex for **`F`**,**`M`** and **`I`**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(LEN(REGEXREPLACE(H11:H400, "[^FMI]", ))))
```

[image]

---

or for **`F`**, **`M`**, **`I`**, **`f`**, **`m`** and **`i`**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(LEN(REGEXREPLACE(H11:H400, "[^FMIfmi]", ))))
```

[image: 0]